# compactness of thes sequence set

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, compactness

Let $S$ be a compact (in the usual topology) subset of $\mathbb R^n$, let $W = \{(q_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\,\mid\, q_k\in S\}$ be the set of all the sequences taking elements in $S$, let $(f_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of continuous functions $f_k:W\to\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$.
For a fixed $\epsilon>0$ consider the set $U_\epsilon=\{q\in W\,\mid\,f_k(q)\ge \epsilon, \forall k\in\mathbb N\}$. I'm wondering what can I conclude about the topological properties of $U_\epsilon$.
My claim  is that $U_\epsilon$ is compact, but I'm very weak in topology and my probably terrible attempt to prove that is the following.
$W$ is compact in the product topology, being in a bijection with $\prod_{n\in\mathbb N} S$, hence since $W\subset S$ it suffices to show that $S$ is closed.
for a fixed $k$ one has that $f_k(U_\epsilon) = [\epsilon, A_k]$ for some constant $A_k$. This should come from the continuity of $f_k$ and the compactness of $W$.
But this also means (isn't it?) that $f^{-1}_k([\epsilon,A_k])$ is closed, and if I'm not wrong  (which is quite probable) $U_\epsilon = \cap_{k\in\mathbb N} f_k^{-1}([\epsilon,A_k])$, and thus since $U_\epsilon$ is the intersection of (infinitely many) closed sets it is closed and hence compact.
Does this make sense to you?

Comment: What topology are you imposing on $W$?

Comment: well $S$ is compact, I think I can suppose wrt the topology induced by the infinity norm. $W$ is isomorphic (I guess) to $\prod_{n\in\mathbb N} S$, therefore I thought that the product topology should be fine...does this make sense to you?

Comment: I asked because there are several natural topologies on $W$, and you can’t even talk about continuity of the functions $f_k$ until you pick one of those topologies. If you use the product topology, then for each $k\in\Bbb N$ the set of $q$ s.t. $f_k(q)\ge\epsilon$ is closed in $W$ and hence compact, and $U_\epsilon$, the intersection of these over $k$, is indeed also compact.

Comment: so my sketch is correct?

Comment: It’s a bit clumsier than necessary, but yes, it’s basically correct. You don’t need to mention $A_k$, for instance: the fact that $\{x\in\Bbb R_{\ge 0}:x\ge\epsilon\}$ is closed is enough to ensure that its inverse image under each $f_k$ is closed in $W$, and the intersection of closed sets is closed, so $U_\epsilon$ is closed. Then appeal to the compactness of $W$, and you’re done.

Comment: yep I know. I'm learning, I need clumsierness... Thanks a lot

Comment: You’re welcome; glad to help.